# Unable to connect to deployed express API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have a deployed api on Heroku. When i try to use it in my localhost or on my deployed frontend, I get the status of fail and the following in the headers

```
Request URL: my-url
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Remote Address: my-remote-address
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Here's the API

```
const app = express()

app.enable('trust proxy')

app.use(cors())

app.options('*', cors())

app.use(helmet())

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use(morgan('dev'))
}

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '2mb' }))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this all of the server code? It doesn’t look like the server is running (e.g.
app.listen()).

Comment: Oh, it is listening, I just showed the part of the code i implemented cors and trust proxy